# SQL Statement performance slow

Tags: mysql, performance, database-performance

I developed an importer which itereates through a file (10K + rows) and writes a CSV file into a MySQL db. Unfortunately this is super slow!
Could you please advice me how to improve the following code?

```
for($i=1; $i<count($data); $i++) {
                                        $rowData = $data[$i];
                                        if(isset($rowData[0])){
                                            $brandingPositionDataSql = 'SELECT * from branding_position WHERE sku_simple_product ="'.$rowData[0].'" AND branding_position_de ="'.$rowData[1].'" AND branding_id = "'.$rowData[8].'" AND handling_group_id = "'.$rowData[9].'" AND pre_cost_id = "'.$rowData[11].'"';
                                            $fetchBradingData = $connection->fetchAll($brandingPositionDataSql);

                                            if(count($fetchBradingData) >= 1){
                                                $updateBrandingDataSql = 'UPDATE branding_position SET sku_simple_product="'.$rowData[0].'", branding_position_de   ="'.$rowData[1].'",branding_position_en="'.$rowData[2].'",branding_position_fr  ="'.$rowData[3].'",branding_position_es="'.$rowData[4].'",branding_position_it  ="'.$rowData[5].'",branding_position_pl="'.$rowData[6].'",branding_position_nl="'.$rowData[7].'",branding_id="'.$rowData[8].'",is_branding_incl='.$rowData[10].' WHERE sku_simple_product ="'.$rowData[0].'" AND  branding_position_de ="'.$rowData[1].'" AND  branding_id = "'.$rowData[8].'" AND handling_group_id = "'.$rowData[9].'" AND pre_cost_id = "'.$rowData[11].'"';
                                                $connection->query($updateBrandingDataSql);
                                            }else{
                                                $sql1 = 'INSERT INTO branding_position (sku_simple_product, branding_position_de, branding_position_en, branding_position_fr, branding_position_es, branding_position_it, branding_position_pl, branding_position_nl, branding_id, handling_group_id, is_branding_incl, pre_cost_id) VALUES ("'.$rowData[0].'","'.$rowData[1].'","'.$rowData[2].'","'.$rowData[3].'","'.$rowData[4].'","'.$rowData[5].'","'.$rowData[6].'","'.$rowData[7].'","'.$rowData[8].'","'.$rowData[9].'",'.$rowData[10].',"'.$rowData[11].'")';
                                                $connection->query($sql1);
                                            }
                                          }
                                        }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show us the _generated_ queries.  It is too messy to guess at them.

Answer (score 0):

@Rick James:

Here is some sample data

@RickJames 
Here is one example for the queries above:

```
SELECT  *
    from  branding_position
    WHERE  sku_simple_product ="01-06721001-00000"
      AND  branding_position_de ="Oberseite - 20.00 x 0.00 / 0.00"
      AND  branding_id = "01-DB1"
      AND  handling_group_id is NULL
      AND  pre_cost_id = "01-A.STK";

UPDATE  branding_position SET sku_simple_product="01-06721001-00000",
        branding_position_de ="Oberseite - 20.00 x 0.00 / 0.00",
        branding_position_en="Oberseite - 20.00 x 0.00 / 0.00",
        branding_position_fr ="Oberseite - 20.00 x 0.00 / 0.00",
        branding_position_es="Oberseite - 20.00 x 0.00 / 0.00",
        branding_position_it ="Oberseite - 20.00 x 0.00 / 0.00",
        branding_position_pl="Oberseite - 20.00 x 0.00 / 0.00",
        branding_position_nl="Oberseite - 20.00 x 0.00 / 0.00",
        branding_id="01-DB1",is_branding_incl='0'
    WHERE  sku_simple_product ="01-06721001-00000"
      AND  branding_position_de ="Oberseite - 20.00 x 0.00 / 0.00"
      AND  branding_id = "01-DB1"
      AND  handling_group_id = ""
      AND  pre_cost_id = "01-A.STK ";
```

Answer (score 0):

I still don't understand what you are doing.  But here are some tips:

- Use `LOAD DATA INFILE ...` to copy a CSV file into a table.  It is very fast.
- If the data (from the `LOAD`) needs manipulating (before `UPDATEing` or `INSERTing`), `LOAD` into an extra table, then do mass manipulations.
- That `SELECT` and `UPDATE` need a 5-column index on the 5 columns mentioned in the `WHERE` clause; they can be in any order.
- Consider using `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` to avoid the select + existence check + update.  You can probably do a single IODKU for the entire `LOADed` data from the extra table.